# JavaScript document.body.style.backgroundColor does not work in while loop

Tags: javascript

I'm using while loop to prompt user to enter for changing background-foreground color until user enters no.But the color does not change during run time, color only changes when user says no and loop breaks, not every time it is entered. So only the color/value entered at last takes effect on page. When I run it in debug mode, it works fine.

```js
function page_color()
{
 while(1)
 {
 var input1=prompt("What is your favourite background color"); 
 if (input1=='No' || input1=='no')
  break;
 document.body.style.backgroundColor = input1;

 var input2=prompt("What is your favourite foreground color");
 if(input2=='No' || input2=='no')
  break;
 document.body.style.color = input2;
 }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="page_color()">click here to change foreground and background color of page</button>
```

Comment: because javascript is not multi-threaded, and your loop prevents the browser to refresh the display. In ten words, this is something like that. This is not the proper way to do your stuff. You may use a `setTimeout` to call `page_color` some time later (500ms for example). This will let the browser process other threads (such as refreshing view)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you need a while loop inside the the page_colour function.

The following code seems to run just fine.

```html
<script>
  function page_color()
{

    var input1=prompt("What is your favourite background color"); 
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = input1;

    var input2=prompt("What is your favourite foreground color");
    document.body.style.color = input2;  

}
</script>
<button onclick="page_color()">click here to change foreground and background color of page</button>
```

Anyways, **The answer to your question** is given by W3schools.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp

> Do not overuse this method, as it prevents the user from accessing other parts of the page until the box is closed. The prompt() method returns the input value if the user clicks "OK". If the user clicks "cancel" the method returns null.

Since, the prompt and alert statements are blocking your application flow, developers do not use it. (also because it looks ugly)

**Alternative to prompt?**

Use the `input` field to collect user input data and add an onClick event handler to run your page_colour function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm trying to solve this : 
Prompt the user to enter his favorite background and foreground color. Receive the values and apply the same as the page’s background and foreground. Keep prompting the user for these details until the user says no.
So prompt and while are required.

Comment: @KuljeetSidhu But let me tell you that `prompt` blocks the flow of the code. So using it is not a wise choice.